# New Variable Woocommerce product not showing variations, price, or add to cart on front end

Tags: plugins

I've only just installed Woocommerce to a network enabled Wordpress install.

On one of the network sites, I:

1. added a product,
2. added attributes,
3. turned the product into a variable product,
4. went to the variations tab, clicked "Go" for "toggle Enabled"
5. on the variations tab, selected prices, "Go", and entered a price.

On the [front end](http://tech.doig.com.au/product/responsive-one-page-website-templates-parallax-effect/), no product variations drop down shows, no price, and no add to cart shows.

Answer (score 1):

I have been having this same issue for the past week. With all these steps you guys have mentioned, the variations would still not show up. I figured out how to get them to work as they should.

With all the steps mentioned above, you MUST also have a "Price". Once I did this, the product page has everything (variables, add to cart, etc) that is suppose to show.

**Variations-Bulk Edit (dropdown)-prices**
Then add your price for the product and Update the page, then refresh your product page, and Voila! Do not put a $ in the price, just 0.00 format. (NOTE: my prices are all set to $0.00 because our customers are not all on the same Volume or pricing.)

Comment: Well done @user43592.

Answer (score 0):

Between steps 3 and 4, there are an extra couple of steps required to actually create the different variations for the product.

1. After changing the product to a variable product, you need to go back into the attributes tab and check **Use for variations**.  This needs to be selected otherwise the variations can't be created from those attributes.
2. On the variations tab, you need to either click **Link All Variations**, or click **Add Variation** and choose the attribute value to set up each variation.

While the 'toggle enabled' and 'price' bulk actions don't display any error messages if done without these steps, they don't do anything unless the variations have themselves first been created.

Comment: Thanks Sarah.  If I go to the attributes tab, there is no button or link to "use for variations".  If I go to the variations tab, the list of attributes has already been turned into a list of variations.